# Colors not showing in Graphics3D

Tags: graphics3d, color

The following code works, except that the colors aren't showing in the output.  Wh?  I probably made a trivial mistake, but I'm yet unable to find it.

```
  Flatten[Table[{x, y, z} = 
      {RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}], RandomReal[{-10, 10}]};
    p = 0.1;
    {u, v, w} = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0};
    NestList[(u += RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, s]];
       v += RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, s]];
       w += RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, s]];
       # + p {u, v, w}) &, {x, y, z}, 50],
    {s, 0.1, 1, 0.05}], 1];
PlotColor = ColorData["SunsetColors"];

Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.1], {PlotColor[Norm[#]], Sphere[#, 0.1]}& /@ RandomWalkCoords}, 
  Boxed -> False, Background -> Black, Lighting -> "Neutral", SphericalRegion -> True]
```

I'm not very familiar with this way of programming *Mathematica* (I'm on version 7.0 by the way), but I'm learning!

The output should show a bunch of random curves made of small balls (no lines), with a radial color gradient.

Maybe there's a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: If you remove the `Lighting->"Neutral"` option, your code should work.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make the SunsetColors to be used.  There's something else.

Comment: ah, yes, sorry - missed they weren't normalised to 1. As the answer says, dividing the `Norm` by the max will do. Also, why `Sphere` and not `Point`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Colour functions from ColorData take values between 0 and 1.  You're giving it much higher values.

Do this:

```
max = Max[Norm /@ RandomWalkCoords]
```

then change `PlotColor[Norm[#]]` to `PlotColor[Norm[#]/max]`.

Side comment: it's good practice not to create symbols with names starting with capital letters.  This way you can be sure you'll avoid conflicts with either built-in or package symbols.

Comment: AAaah !  Thanks !  It's perfectly clear !  :-)